# Yii: виджет CGridView и фильт по датам

Tags: php, yii

Нужна подсказка.
Есть CGridView с столбцами типа номер, дата и время, название.
Нужно сделать выборку за периоду, т.е. нужно два поля для ввода верхней и нижней временной границы через виджет CJuiDatePicker.
Обычная настройка параметра filter предполагает одно поле ввода(или один выпадающий список, или один календарь).

1. Как сделать два поля ввода?
2. Как заставить CGridView с этим работать?

Answer (score 1):

В пакете YiiBooster для диапазонов используется виджет `TbDateRangePicker`, а он использует [эту](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/) js-библиотеку. И верхняя и нижняя граница вводятся в одно поле фильтра с разделителем " - ". А дальше - дело техники. Если модель построена через gii, разбор и подстановка условий делается в методе `search()`.